# How to make text be on top in use (Flutter) in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

so I want to make a simple text in a flutter framework, but I don't know to make the text for going on the top of the text, this is the example of the image I want to be on top :

[image]

this is my DetailPage.dart :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          title: Text(
            'Detail ' + itemJudul,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )),
      body: Column(

        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: Image.asset(itemImage)),
          Text(
            itemJudul,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 30.0),
          ),
          Text(itemSub),
          Text('Sisa Item =' + qty),
          Container(
            width: 200,
            child: Text("Bahan Bahan",
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold) // has impact
                ),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text(
              listbahanan,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text(
              listbahan2,
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by on top? On top of what? Where should it be?

Comment: you don't see my image screenshot.

Comment: hey, @Mobina are you understand about my question.

Comment: There are a lot of texts in that image, but I assume you want the 11-18 items of the list to be beside 1-10 items. Also, please include your code in your question.

Comment: please see again my answer, I was update my answer

Answer (score 0):

U can use two columns wrapped in a row.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
          child: Text(
            listbahanan,
            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
       ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: Text(
           listbahan2,
           textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
     )
  ],
),
```

Comment: in my case I was using      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight, but is not work.

Comment: Just wrap those two containers in a row so that they are placed side by side instead of one after another. Use Expanded if the text tends to go out of screen.

Comment: you mean I must put Row() under text of (    Center(child: Image.asset(itemImage)), ) , like that

Comment: yes, remove the last two containers and replace them with a Row containing those containers. That way they will be side by side. @Misbagas

Comment: when I change my last two containers to Row () , I get eror.

Comment: the error is, expected to find ')' , and the error is, expected to find ']'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Row` to align two lists side by side. Also, I don't think it's a good idea to store a list as string, better use `List` for storing and `ListView` for displaying the list items.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
          title: Text(
            'Detail ' + itemJudul,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          )),
      body: Column(

        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(child: Image.asset(itemImage)),
          Text(
            itemJudul,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.redAccent, fontSize: 30.0),
          ),
          Text(itemSub),
          Text('Sisa Item =' + qty),
          Container(
            width: 200,
            child: Text("Bahan Bahan",
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold) // has impact
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          ),
          Row( // this is new
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible( // this is new
                child: Text(
                  listbahanan,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                ),
              ),
              Flexible( // this is new
                child: Text(
                  listbahan2,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: when I check my logcat , I get eror , the error is : A RenderFlex overflowed by 12 pixels on the right.

Comment: That's because I used `Padding` to make space between two lists. I've updated my answer. Check if it works. @Misbagas

Comment: instead of using padding use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`  in row,it will create space between the row childrens @Mobina

Comment: You're right. It'll work that way, too. I'll approve your edit as soon as SO let me. @Morbius